# How do I cleanly remove apache2 server on ubuntu server and then reinstall?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, package-management

I am having some wierd issues with Apache2 server on my ubuntu server. I believe some configuration files may have been tampered with. What is the easiest way to remove apache2 completely from my server. I am aware of how to install by using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

but, I just want to make sure I completely remove apache2.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Run the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2
sudo apt-get remove apache2-common
```

Comment: I did this and I still have `apache2-bin`, `apache2-data`, `apache2-utils`. Aren't these parts of apache2 and therefore should have been deleted when executing what you say?

Answer (score 81):

First stop your server obviously:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Remove apache2 packages and dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

If you manually modified or installed stuff, apt might not remove it. Check what's left:

```
whereis apache2
```

Have a look whats inside these directories, and if you're confident you want to trash it, manually remove the directories. In my case:

```
sudo rm -Rf /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/include/apache2
```

Comment: This answer is more complete than the accepted answer. The full sequence of commands is:

`sudo service apache2 stop`    
`sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2`    
`sudo apt-get remove apache2-common`    
`sudo apt-get autoremove`    
`whereis apache2`    
`apache2: /etc/apache2`    
`sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2`

Comment: Great thorough answer. :-0

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Just had loads of trouble with Apache2 and this saved me from reinstall my OS (Linux Mint 14 MATE). Thanks!

Comment: Simply: "sudo apt-get remove apache2;sudo apt-get autoremove --purge"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this out.

```
APACHE_PKGS=`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep apache | cut -f 1`
```

In your Terminal then check to see if it's there:

```
echo $APACHE_PKGS
```

Should show something like:

apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common and many more. Then you run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $APACHE_PKGS
sudo apt-get install $APACHE_PKGS
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

These commands will completely remove Apache2, all its configs and logs:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt purge apache2
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apache2
```

Install Apache2:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```