# How do I setup my apache2 server for ownCloud?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, owncloud

Disclaimer: Running Linux Mint 14 MATE

Everywhere I look I see that you have to enable .htaccess for Apache2 Server when running ownCloud. Well nobody says where to do that!

I have owncloud's data running from

- /var/lib/owncloud/data
- and a 750 GB harddrive mounted to /var/lib/owncloud/data (I could not get owncloud to access /media/750GB/data)

nano nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default results in:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All <-I switched this from NONE*************
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all <-I switched this from NONE*************
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

I don't even see the directory for owncloud in there. Just /var/www, but my owncloud data is running from /var/lib/owncloud/data. **How do I setup .htaccess for that folder?**

Such that the following error in the ownCloud admin page disappears:

> Your data directory and your files are probably accessible from the internet. The .htaccess file that ownCloud provides is not working. We strongly suggest that you configure your webserver in a way that the data directory is no longer accessible or you move the data directory outside the webserver document root.

**Where is the .htaccess file that ownCloud provides?**

Is it this one?

> /usr/share/owncloud/.htaccess

The contents of that file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /owncloud/core/templates/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /owncloud/core/templates/404.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value memory_limit 512M
<IfModule env_module>
  SetEnv htaccessWorking true
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^apps/([^/]*)/(.*\.(css|php))$ index.php?app=$1&getfile=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For htaccess to work  mod_rewrite.so has to be activated. [see here](http://www.tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/)

Depending on your linux distribution, this is done in differently.

For Ubuntu it is simply

```
root@VSRV0301 ~# a2enmod rewrite
```

To activate htaccess for a specific folder outside the www-root just adding

```
<Directory /var/lib/owncloud> # or the folder owncloud lives in
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all <-I switched this from NONE*************
</Directory>
```

to your apache config should work.

Comment: your post does not answer my question as stated above "How do I setup .htaccess for that folder?"

Comment: Oh sorry. All you should have to do is copy the `<Directory /var/www/>` node and change the new path to `/var/lib/owncloud/data`.

Comment: You can have as much of these Directory nodes as you want, declaring settings for (almost?) any physical directory you wish. No need to overwrite the settings for /var/www.
What I miss in your apache config is the Alias directive binding /var/lib/owncloud/data to your www-root or a subfolder e.g. `Alias /owncloud /var/lib/ownclod/data`. The directory node should be in the same config as this.

Comment: After running a2enmod rewrite, I get 
Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: I feel like you are onto something here. I am almost to the point of getting this to work. I am still getting the error in ownCloud after adding the node pointing to /var/lib/owncloud/data. Also, I ran /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. I added an important piece to this question in my original post.

Comment: Try removing "/data" from the path, This actually is the path where all the user files are stored. The Owncloud application itself should be in /var/lib/owncloud.

Comment: Ok I tried that and restarted the apache server. There error is persisting.

Comment: As a workaround you could try to move the data/ folder out of the owncloud directory (to /var/lib/owncloud_data perhaps) and change the owncloud configuration accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Duke for your time and effort! In the end, I was able to get things working in /var/www/owncloud (see my complicated answer above)!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wiping out apache2 and owncloud 3.0 or whatever it was and reinstalled apache2 with owncloud 4.5.7. It is working now.

1. **Wipe out Apache2** with this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/182277/how-do-i-cleanly-remove-apache2-server-on-ubuntu-server-and-then-reinstall):

> sudo service apache2 stop

- Remove apache2 packages and dependencies:

> sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
>   sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

- If you manually modified or installed stuff, apt might not remove it. Check what's left:

> whereis apache2

- Have a look whats inside these directories, and if you're confident you want to trash it, manually remove the directories. In my case:

> sudo rm -Rf /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/include/apache2

---

2. **Wipe out owncloud**

> sudo apt-get --purge remove owncloud

- Try to find any lingering files and remove them

> sudo rm -r /var/lib/owncloud

- Remove MySQL database

> mysql -u root -p
>   drop database owncloud;

- Remove oc users from mysql

> I forgot the commands, I will try to figure it out again.

---

ownCloud 4.5.7 following the part of this procedure under xUbuntu 12.10 for the actual apt-get install:

> http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud

and the following for .htaccess and the rest

> http://samiux.blogspot.co.at/2013/02/howto-owncloud-with-apache-on-ubuntu.html

Now things work, data no longer located in */var/lib/owncloud*, rather in */var/www/owncloud*
There is an .htaccess file under */var/www/owncloud/data*
Permissions for all files in data set to www-data:www-data