# Apache2 doesn't work after changing the hostname of my Ubuntu-system

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I changed the hostname (from something like "Ubuntu-14.04" to "mysitename.com") of my ubuntu-server. I also changed fully qualified domain name accordingly. After that I reloaded my apache2 server.

After that only the default config started to work with the default apache-page. I tried to add other configs, but they didn't work.

So I tried to reinstall apache2 (at first I'd been intended to reconfigure apache2, but there is no such command (or so I think) and I just decided to choose the simple path - reinstallation). 
But with the same result.

After that I tried to remove apache2 completely. I deleted every file that had "apache" in its name and installed apache2 again. Now it doesn't even show any message when I type "service apache2" in the console.

How can I reanimate apache2 and make it able to recognize configs other than the default one?

Thank you.

update. Ok, I just reinstalled Ubuntu. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new vhost, you should put the vhost file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and do `sudo a2ensite mynewsite` where mynewsite is the filename. Then restart Apache to see the changes.

But first, check this link on how to cleanly reinstall Apache. ([How do I cleanly remove apache2 server on ubuntu server and then reinstall?](https://serverfault.com/questions/182277/how-do-i-cleanly-remove-apache2-server-on-ubuntu-server-and-then-reinstall))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reinstalled Apache how it's described in the link, hoping that this time it'll work, but it didn't. The installation didn't have any errors, but when I type "service apache2" in the console, nothing happens:
`root@mysite ~ # service apache2

root@mysite ~ # `